# Enabling Hugepages at boot time on centos 7

Tags: centos, grub2, virtual-machine, grub

I am trying to enable hugepages for use with ovs and DPDK on centos 7. I have tried to edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` see code below.  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet hugepagesz=1G hugepages=16 hugepagesz=2M hugepages=2048 iommu=pt intel_iommu=on isolcpus=1-13,15-27"`

`grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` :

However after i reboot and issue the `cat /proc/cmdline`, the resulting output does not show appended hugepage entries. :-(

`[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/cmdline`

[image]

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-
root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb
quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

`[root@localhost ~]# grep Huge /proc/meminfo` :

[image: hugepages values]

Am i missing anything please?

Comment: (A random troubleshooting step): Did the change make it to `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`? (that's a plain text file, use `less` or your favorite editor to check)

Comment: Hi @derobert thanks for the useful tip. the changes actually made it to /boot/grub2/grub.cfg. See output here **** linuxefi /vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet hugepagesz=1G hugepages=16 hugepagesz=2M hugepages=2048 iommu=pt intel_iommu=on isolcpus=1-13,15-27**** I am not sure why the hugepage values still come up with zero values after rebooting. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the problem had to do with the location of the grub file, and the fact that I was using the wrong path for it.

I orignially tried to use

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```

But I should have used /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg. as the path to the grub file. So the actual command should be

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

This is probably because it is a UEFI-based system. The [Centos wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Grub2) states UFEI-based systems use a different path to the default grub file.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same thing on CentOS 7.4.

Two things I noticed in your case:

1. You have two entries for `hugepagesz` (1G and 2M) and `hugepage` (16 and 2048). I'm not sure whether you can do that.
2. I generated the config file into /etc/grub2.cfg before reboot:

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
   ```

In my case, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` has the following value (50 1G pages):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on isolcpus=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=50"
```

Also check whether your kernel has required options enabled (see [DPDK manual, section 2.3.1](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html) for these):

```
grep <OPTION>= /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

And check whether your CPU supports 1GB pages (searching for pdpe1gb cpu flag):

```
grep pdpe1gb /proc/cpuinfo
```

EDIT: Also check whether you mounted the memory properly (see [DPDK manual, section 2.3.2.2](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html)).